# block certain ajax action in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

How can I block certain ajax action in wordpress, i.e. with this work I want prevent calling wp-ajax.php when that ajax action executed. I know that ajax action function name.

Comment: use the `wp_ajax_nopriv` hook

Comment: Hook name is 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_1_wc_emailer' and I want to block it and its callback function from running. I can't find where this hook is written in site. is there any action hook to add in functions.php to prevent callback function?

Comment: Open your theme's `functions.php` file or a custom plugin file.

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_action', 'block_ajax_action');`

`function block_ajax_action() { wp_die('This AJAX action is blocked.');}`

replace `your_ajax_action` and `your_callback_function` with your actual AJAX action name and callback function.

Comment: `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_1_wc_emailer', 'wp_1_wc_emailer'); 
function wp_1_wc_emailer() { 
 wp_die('This AJAX action is blocked.'); 
} ` This is what I wrote. But not works

Comment: with which priority in action hook, higher or lower ?